# Button sort php table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Got a school assignment to do (not much time left), ordering a sql table when pressing a button.. However, I've tried for days but haven't made it work.. Any Ideas? The table is called ratedcomments. And it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjvEq.png
.. So when pressing for example name, it should order the whole table after name in ASC, and when pressing it again, it should order it DESC

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

    <hr>

        <table id="notes">
            <td class="short"><input type="button" value="Date"></td>  
            <td class="short"><input type="submit" value="Name" name="n"><?php 
    if (isset($_POST["n"])) 
    {
/*What should I write here in order to trigger the ASC sort when pressing
 the button, with the value "name"??
I've thought of "SELECT * FROM `ratedcomments` ORDER BY name ASC"; 
but I don't know how to put it up in Mysql.. */
    }


    ?></td>  
            <td class="short"><input type="button" value="Email" name="e"></td> 
            <td class="long"><input type="button" value="Comment" name="c"></td> 
            <td class="short"><input type="button" value="Rating" name="r"></td> 
            <td class="short"><b>Delivery type</b></td> 
            <td class="shorter"></td> 
            <td class="shorter"></td> 
            <?php echo $tablerows; ?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: Look at this for SELECT in PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp.  You idea is the good one.   Form handling is here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Well, it's a shame that you've not got much time left, but generally you'd handle sorting client side, with some javascript acting upon a bunch of unsorted list lelements.

Comment: @Nic3500 can I put this inside the if-statement? : 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `ratedcomments` ORDER BY name ASC");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

Comment: @Nic3500  I've already formed my code in the same way as it shows in the first link you've sent

Comment: Once you run your query, you need to do a foreach on the results and output each row, in the format you want.

Comment: @Nic3500 Try and link to the official documentation whenever possible. Third party sites, *especially* w3schools, are often wildly out of date. That one includes, for no particular reason, the obsolete procedural style, for example.

Comment: @tadman: ok noted.  But I find the official documentation rather dry and difficult to learn from for brand new developpers.  Any other suggestions you know about?

Comment: @Nic3500 The official documentation also has tremendously helpful comments at the end which add more community flavour and explain nuances the documentation might not have. For "brand new" developers it's essential to get a good introduction book to MySQL and PHP in general, find one that fits your style. Reference documentation is typically dry and to the point by design.

Comment: @Nic3500 The real problem is with w3schools itself where they seem uninterested in best practices, their content languishes for years without updates, and yet have incredible search rankings that lure in too many developers. Many of the PHP+MySQL questions here are the result of the damage that site has done.

Comment: @tadman: if you know of another good source sites for beginners I would be interested.  Since books can also be out of date.  And so many beginners end up here with poor questions, it would be helpful.

Comment: @nic3500 [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a good place to start, but if you know of any other good resources I'll advertise those as well.